# Pixel Value in a Lat and Long location in Envi IDL

Tags: envi, idl

I am new with ENVI IDL,I want to get pixel value of each band in an image in specified lat and long location.I can do a loop among bands in image using this code

```
ENVI_OPEN_FILE,'E:\MASTER\Payan_Name\DataSer\Output\162\0730\1-1Georefrence_BIP\Subset_BIP.hdr', R_FID=FID, NO_REALIZE=1
ENVI_FILE_QUERY, FID, ns=ns, nl=nl, nb=nb, data_type=data_type, descrip=descrip, bnames=bnames, sensor_type=sensor_type, wavelength_units=wavelength_units, dims=dims

for b=0,nb-1,1 do begin
  indata = ENVI_GET_DATA(FID=fid,POS=b,DIMS=dims)
endfor
```

But I don't know how to get pixel value at lat and long,I searched and found a library which name is `Rdpix` is used to get pixel value at mouse location but I want it at specified lat and long location,
Can Some one please help me find the solution or give me some clues to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the license, ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES is the right function to solve your issue. You can reference  [this website](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVI_CONVERT_FILE_COORDINATES.html).

Comment: thank you for your help.This gunction converts Xy to map cordinates..How can I get the pixel value?

Comment: first, get the x and y, and then indata[x,y] is the pixel value.